# Swapping values in a stream using lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I  tried to use lambdas to swap elements in the char[] array. Does this mean that I am trying to change the stream while it is streaming ?

If that is a problem then a new stream will do. How should this be done ? I am not looking for 
a Comparator. I would like to work with this code as it is without using any API but lambdas.

I am printing using lambdas in this code now.

```
public class DutchNationalFlag {

    private static final int N = 10;

    private static char[] flags = new char[]{'R','B','B','R','R','B','B','R','R','B'};

    public static void main( String... argv){

        new String(flags).chars().mapToObj(i -> (char)i).forEach(System.out::println);

        int m = 0,  k = 0;
        while (m != N)  {
            if (flags[m] == 'B') { }
            else {
                swap(flags,k,m); 
                k = k+1;
            }
            m = m+1;
        } 
        new String(flags).chars().mapToObj(i -> (char)i).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static void swap(char[] flags, int k, int m) {

        char temp = flags[k];
        flags[k] = flags[m];
        flags[m] =  temp;

    }

}
```

Possible Solution 1:

This doesn't do exactly what the original code does. It doesn't swap and doesn't advance *k* which is the boundary between **'B'** and **'R'**.But it produces the result and I thought something like *zip* could be useful.

```
    Stream<Character> stream1 = 
    IntStream.range(0, flags.length).mapToObj(i -> (char)flags[i]);

    Stream<Character> stream2 = 
    IntStream.range(0, flags.length).mapToObj(i -> (char)flags[i]);


    Stream.concat(stream2.filter(x-> (x == 'B')), stream1.filter( y->(y == 'R')  )).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to do?

Comment: Let's assume I receive a finite stream of chars. I want to move all R's to the end and all B's to the beginning by swapping. I also maintain a boundary counter. All values before the counter are B's and all values after the counter are R's.

Comment: You are unclear. Your question doesn't even contain a question. Also "swapping" and "moving" make no sense for streams. You seem to be confusing a description of how an output stream is related to an input stream with algorithms for making that so. Please rewrite your question to make your task and question clear. PS Make your question self-contained: drop the link and incorporate relevant text.

Comment: You have not made your question clear. Please quote the assignment that you were given.

Comment: Not an assignment. I think the original problem can be ignored. I have a stream of values. Can I compare the downstream values with other upstream values ? Can I create new streams with new values based on the comparison ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not running into any problems with changing a stream while streaming it, because you're using an array of characters. Arrays are not streams (though an array can be used as a stream). There's no problems with modifying an array as you traverse it. The problem I think you're referring to would occur if you were using Java *iterators*, which are implicitly used whenever you use a `for (SomeType item : container)` loop.

This is because when traversing containers *in general*, there is no way to safely guarantee that you can modify it as you traverse it with the exception of being able to remove the single element you're currently using in the loop iteration. If you want to do more complex in-place modifcations, you need a less general container type, like an array.

This is unrelated from the Java 8 Stream API, which is meant for processing streams in a way inspired by functional programming using map/filter/reduce. The purpose of using this API is for modifying large amounts of data either concurrently or sequentially in a manner that avoids most of the issues that concurrent modification faces. You're not actually *using* any streams in your code, and there's no reason to, so I don't think that's what you want. Stick to an imperative `for` here, as in-place modifications of arrays are what `for` loops are best at.

```
public static void main (String... args) {

    for (Char char : chars) {
        System.out.println(char);
    }
    int k = 0;
    for (int m = 0; m != M; m++) {
        if (flags[m] != 'B') {
            swap(flags, k++, m);
        }
    }
    for (Char char : chars) {
        System.out.println(char);
    }
}
```

Lambdas and streams are very, very powerful tools, but they're not the proper tools for this job. You're working with a simple array and you want to do in-place modifications. Never play an ace if a two will do.

Comment: :-) That wasn't my point. I had actually coded it using the older style.

Comment: Well yes, but my point is that this isn't a difference of style - these are separate problem domains. Streams aren't meant to solve the kind of problem you presented.

Comment: Not even if you have a very large array and cores ?

Comment: If you have a very large amount of data, an array is not the best place to put it because you have to hold the entirety of it in memory to modify small portions of it, and you'll run into shared-memory issues with concurrency. It's easy enough to divide up the array into portions that can be handled each by an individual thread, but that does nothing to solve the memory issue and if you mess it up you'll introduce very subtle bugs. 99% of the time, such massive amounts of data are from an external source such as a file, and those can be processed with streams explicitly.

Comment: Jack (& @MohanRadhakrishnan): I'm guessing that the OP is supposed to stream output that is a certain function of an input stream but is unclear about streams, the specification, the solution and what question they're asking.